# How do I see detailed log messages from Jenkins emailing?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, email-ext

I am having [trouble getting email-ext working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12748411/why-are-jenkins-extended-emails-not-including-extended-information).  I've looked at the system log ("Manage Jenkins"/"System Log"), and it shows the job succeeded in running, but nothing about how email works.

Is there some way to turn up logging so I can watch the emailing portion of either default or email-ext firing?  Maybe I can tell why email is not working if I can see what it's trying to do.

**Edit**: We're running Jenkins 1.484.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this:

1. go to configure system-system log,and add a new recorder
2. Choose a name that makes sense to you.
3. configure loggers and their levels whose output you'd like to collect

you can look there:https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Logging